# ¿Como coger fecha de modificación de un archivo en Python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría poder coger la fecha de modificación de los archivos que itero en el bucle para poder realizar una condición dentro de ella.

Pero no sé que estoy haciendo mal que no me coge la fecha, ¿alguien me podría decirme como realizarlo?

```py
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(pathFiles): 
    for file in files:
        path = (folder + file)
        print(path)
        ti_m = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(path))
        print(ti_m)
```

Estoy haciendo un `print` del `ti_m` pero no me imprime

Comment: Tal como está el código al crear `path` solo concatenas `folder` y `file` en tu pregunta no es visible lo que contengan esas dos variables pero si no existe una diagonal `/` entre `folder` y `file` te va a devolver error. Aparte de ese detalle al ejecutar el código funciona de forma correcta. Por favor agrega los valores de tus variables que reproduzcan el comportamiento que describes y sería bueno agregar el sistema operativo que usas (Funcionan un poco diferente)

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No se puede publicar segun que variables ja que son privadas del codigo, por lo tanto si hay una variable que es un pathfile i estoi haciendo un bucle se entiende que estoy mirando los archivos de una carpeta no, digo yo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo. Solamente preguntaba como coger la fecha de modificación. Creo que en la variable **path** en vez de hacer `(folder + file)` tenia que realizar lo siguiente:

```
path = (os.path.join(folder,file))
modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getmtime(path)
modificationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))
```

De esta manera me crea el path completo para poder recoger la fecha de modificación.

Comment: En vez de `os.path()` te puede interesar mirar `pathlib` que es un módulo que viene con versiones recientes de Python y que simplifica el manejo de operaciones con rutas y ficheros.

Comment: Gracias @abulafia me lo mirare ;)

Comment: te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta